# how to remove prev foreach data

Tags: php, arrays, regex, arraylist, joomla

```
foreach ($products as $product) {
    echo "SIZE (X х Y х Z),mm: ";
    $myf = [8,4,5]; // my custom fields is X,Y,Z and print it           
    foreach($product->customfields as $field){ // get fields
        if (in_array($field->virtuemart_custom_id, $myf)) {
            $output[] = $field->customfield_value;
        }
    }
    echo implode('x', $output); // is getting re-assigned each time. So whatever the problem is, it is a result of whatever $output is getting assigned with.
}
```

in second product I have this data from first product

**SIZE (X х Y х Z),mm: 280x260x350x290x325x435 (need 290x325x435 only!).**
on each products I have all previous XYZ data from all previous products.

Very mistiq. pls help print data 1 XYZ to 1 product only :)

I thinks implode not correct method

Comment: what is prev? and what's the question?

Comment: previous product.inherits data from all previous products - XYZ

Comment: still don't understand your question is

Comment: in 3 product info i gets combined data XYZ1XYZ2XYZ3, but must be XYZ3 only, please kill combined data

Comment: can i see data of the $products ? i want to run it

Comment: foreach ($products as $product) {
                echo implode('x', $output);  // need kill this combined data i think ((
             }

Comment: no no i  mean i want to see the data inside the `$products` variable

Comment: $products - array of products with data:: XYZ, Size, weight, lenght and other. and products have array of customfields with data id,name, etc

Comment: oh my. can you  edit your question with complete working  example then other can run and fix it for you

Comment: no i cant because its patch for joomla + virtuemart store for display "custom fields".. my custom fields is combined with all previous data, because i impode 'x':: like Size AxBxC

Comment: `$output[] = ` is getting re-assigned each time. So whatever the problem is, it is a result of whatever  $output is getting assigned with.

Answer (score 0):

Just after this line

```
echo implode('x', $output);
```

Add this line

```
unset($output);
```

What this does is this will reset your `$output` to an empty array. No longer your $output has the previous data.

Comment: very well you super

Comment: @boniq If this has solved your problem you can mark this as solved.